# using "multiple"namespaces one-liner

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, inline-namespaces

is there a simplified way to include more namespaces instead of typing every time the same things. This is very annoying, especially in the .h files.

For instance:

Instead of writing:

```
int f() {
    using namespace blabla1;
    using namespace blabla2;
    using namespace blabla3;

}
```

I would prefer:

using myNamespace = blabla1, blabla2, blabla3;

```
int f() {
    using namespace myNamespace;
    /// this will be equivalent to the previous example
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using directives are transitive. So if you aggregate them into a single namespace

```
namespace All {
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
    using namespace C;
}
```

You can then simply do

```
using namespace All;
```

And unqualified name lookup will work.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0fb46c67002ded9)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but if you want to avoid multiple using statements each time, you can wrap the above namespaces, into another namespace:

```
namespace myNameSpace {
  using namespace blabla1;
  using namespace blabla2;
  using namespace blabla3;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
int f() {
    using namespace myNameSpace;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dDjz8u).

Comment: Same solution at the same time, damn, I don't know how do people deal with these cases. Both of you deserve the best answer

Comment: Thanks :) Note that you can only accept one answer, but you can upvote multiple answers if you find them useful.

Comment: I have a new account, so I need some points to upvote. I will definitely upvote both

Comment: ok upvoted both. I am going to put the best answer to StoryTeller only because he explained the that using directives are transitive. Thank you again mate